# Compile JS after HTML loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compiler-construction

So I'm wanting to compile some JS code after the HTML is loaded.

```
var gifApp = angular.module('gifApp', []);

function MainCtrl ($scope) {
  $scope.push = function() {
    $("body").html("<div>{{ 1 + 1 }}</div>")
  }
}
```

Whenever the function `push` is called `{{ 1 + 1 }}` is displayed on the screen when I really want `2`. Is it not possible to compile the code after the window is done loading? If it is possible, how do I fix this.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for "templates"?

Comment: I made a new question referencing specifically the problem I'm having. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061111/compile-js-directive-after-html-loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are feeding the `html()` method a string, it is working correctly. I would change it to something like this:

```
var sum = 1 + 1;
$("body").html("<div>" + sum + "</div>");
```

Comment: Hmm thanks. I have a different variation to the question but you answered it correctly.