# Compile JS Directive after HTML loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm wanting to compile a directive after the HTML is loaded.

```
var gifApp = angular.module('gifApp', []);

gifApp.directive('addition', function() {
  return function(scope, element) {
    element.html("<h1>" + scope.gif.name + "</h1>")

  }
});

function MainCtrl ($scope) {
  $scope.gif = {name: "Cat jumps on car"}

  $scope.push_code = function() {
    $("body").html("<div addition></div>")
  }
}
```

Whenever the function `push_code` is called the gif name is not displayed on the screen. Is it not possible to compile the code after the window is done loading with a directive? If it is possible, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add HTML after the window has loaded but Angular needs to know when you do.  Right now since you're adding the `div` using jQuery Angular doesn't know the DOM has changed.  And thus it doesn't get a chance to apply your directive to your new element.

The way I'd recommend dealing with this is using Angular's built-in version of jQuery called [jQlite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element).

Here's a version of `push_code()` using [jQlite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element):

```
push_code = function() {
   compiled = $compile('<div addition></div>')($scope);
   angular.element(document).find('body').append(compiled)
}
```

Here we create an Angular DOM element and tell Angular to $compile it on the current scope (which will apply your directive).  Then we add that Angular element to the `body` in the jQlite equivalent of your jQuery approach.

Here's a demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/Me2HW/3/

I put the `push_code()` call inside `$timeout` just to demonstrate there's no timing dependency here.  You can make this call whenever you'd like, including well after the window has loaded, and it works.